# $\int fg = 0$ implies $f =0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ an open set and let $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^{k}$, where $k \ge 0$ ($k=0$ implies the functions are only continuous). Note that $k$ can be $k=+\infty$. Suppose:
$$\int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)dx = 0$$
for every $g$ with compact support. Does it follow that $f \equiv 0$?

**Note:** I know the result follows if $\Omega = I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and if $k=0$ or $k=\infty$. I'd like to know if this also holds in the case where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is just an open set and $k \ge 0$ is arbitrary.

**Note 2:** I have sketched a proof as follows.

*Sketch of the proof:* Suppose that $f(x^{*}) \neq 0$ for some $x^{*} \in U$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $f(x^{*}) > 0$. Because $f \in C^{k}(\Omega)$ for some $k\ge 0$, $f$ is, in particular, continuous at $x^{*}$. Thus, there exists an open ball $B_{r}(x^{*})\subset U$ with radius $r$ and centered at $x^{*}$ such that if $x \in B_{r}(x^{*})$ then $f(x) > 0$. Then, take $g$ to be a $C^{k}(\Omega)$ function which is 1 on $\overline{B_{r}(x^{*})}$ and zero otherwise.
$$0 = \int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)dx = \int_{\overline{B_{r}(x^{*})}}f(x)dx $$
which is an absurd!

**The problem** is that I don't know if I can always construct such a function $g$ which is $C^{k}(\Omega)$, $g=1$ inside $\overline{B_{r}(x^{*})}$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it does follow and The result is quite standard.

Comment: Can you help me with some references?

Comment: Indeed, if $f$ is continuous, and $\int fg = 0$ for every $C^\infty$ funciton $g$ with compact support, then $f=0$.  But no, you cannot construct a $g$ as you claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and you can even weaken the hypotheses by a lot more; though the weaker the hypotheses, the more technical the arguments (the ideas remain the same though).

Let me work with the case $k=0$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction there exists an $x_0\in \Omega$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$; for the sake of definiteness, let us assume that $f(x_0)>0$. Then, by continuity, there exists a small open ball $B_r$ of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ and whose closure lies inside $\Omega$ such that for every $x\in \overline{B_r}$, we have $f(x)>0$. Now, let $g$ be a continuous function which is equal to $1$ on $B_{r/2}$, and which decays to $0$ continuously having support within $B_r$ (i.e we're taking the constant function $1$, and "cutting it off" before it reaches the boundary of the ball $B_r$). Then, we can extend $g=0$ outside $B_r$, so we have a continuous function on all of $\Omega$. So,
\begin{align}
0&= \int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)\,dx\tag{by assumption}\\
&= \int_{B_r}f(x)g(x)\,dx \tag{since $g=0$ outisde $B_r$}\\
& \geq \int_{B_{r/2}}f(x)\cdot 1\,dx\\
&>0.
\end{align}
This is clearly a contradiction.

---

As you can see, the idea is pretty simple: suppose $f\neq 0$; then we find some larger compact set on which $f$ does not vanish. Then, we take a cut-off function $g$. Above, I only required $g$ to be continuous; but we by using convolutions we can even find smooth functions. Then, the remainder of the proof proceeds similarly.

Comment: Thank you! So, the sketch of my proof is basically correct!

Comment: @MathMath I just saw your update; yes your idea is essentially right (though maybe you may have to work with $g$ equal to $1$ on a slightly smaller ball). If you really want to track down the various constructions of these smooth functions, you should look up "bump functions/cut-off functions/ smoothing convolutions/mollifiers" etc

Comment: @MathMath by the way you can find these constructions in any (intermediate/advanced) real analysis book or maybe some introductory differential geometry books. For example, I know for sure Folland's real analysis book has results of this kind (in the section on convolutions). I also know Amann and Escher's Analysis III has results of this kind (see the section on convolutions). In this book, they also prove a more general version of the question you asked about: if $f\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ and $\int_{\Omega}fg=0$ for every smooth $g$ with compact support in $\Omega$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds Problem 2-26 is a guided problem which shows you how to construct smooth functions equal to $1$ on a compact set and having compact support within a prescribed open set (like in ncmathsadist's answer). This is a very instructive problem and can be solved without knowing anything about convolutions (well, atleast he doesn't use the term convolution explicitly, but the ideas are very similar, and his problem is well-guided).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but I can't comment

If you admit that $\int f^2 = 0$ implies that $f=0$ then this is pretty straightforward.

The idea is to take $g$ so that you integrate something positive on $\Omega$. Make sure that the $g$ you choose is still with compact support.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the key result. If $K$ is compact and $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then there is a $\psi\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ function of compact support so that $\psi = 1$ on $K$ and so ${\rm supp}(\psi) \subset G$.

Comment: This a very useful result indeed. I believe this is also standard, but if you know where I can find a proof I'd be glad to know. I know how to show the existence of compactly supported functions by defining Mollifiers of the form $\psi(x) = \varphi(1-|x|^{2})$, where $\varphi(x) = e^{-1/x}$ if $x > 0$ and zero otherwise, but these functions are not one inside some compact.

Comment: See Mike Spivak's Calculous on Manifolds